# can autocompletebox in WPF handle suggesting multiple values?

Tags: wpf, autocomplete

I am using AutoCompleteBox and doing a search from the database when a value is entered. The ValueMemberPath is currently equal to "LastName". I would like this box to also handle if an ID number is entered at which point I would do a different search. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean Silverlight's System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox ?

Comment: yea but i am using it with WPF, the WPF Tool Kit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be an issue within the toolkit itself:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/585770/autocompletebox-bug-valuememberpath-is-null?ppud=0&wa=wsignin1.0#tabs